# Alfresco Notifying the original uploader that document is rejected or approved?

Tags: alfresco

For example, I have user A upload a file, user B reviews it, and then user C approves. Is it possible that after approval of user C, an email notification can be sent to user A only, assumming that user A is set to be a member of contributor group (i.e, can Alfresco track the user that uploaded the file)? Because so far, I only know how to send to a whole group) Or the only way for the uploader to know is through the task bar notification?

I'm using Alfresco Community 4.2, Share

Comment: are your using an Activiti Workflow or just the simple rule based Approve & Reject one?

Comment: Just a simple workflow.